# How to store multiple arrays as one array, with array_unshift & array_merge

Tags: php, arrays

### a better clarification version

```
$x = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$array = array_merge($x, $a);
print_r($array);
```

is working perfectly and giving me the following array

```
Array ( [0] => x [1] => y [2] => z [3] => a [4] => b [5] => c )
```

But i have a statement like this **[WHICH IS TOTALLY WRONG AT THE MERGE PART]**

```
$x = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
if(isset($_GET['z'])){
   $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
$array = array_merge($x, $a); //need to assign that to a variable!
print_r($array);
```

But i can't add the $a like this into the `array_merge()`so i assign them to a variable like the following

```
$x = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
if(isset($_GET['z'])){
   $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
$merging = [$x];
if(isset($_GET['z'])){
    array_unshift($merging, $a);
}
$array = array_merge($merging);
print_r($array);
```

But what i get is

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => x [1] => y [2] => z ) 
)
```

And what i want is one single array containing all the values like the first example array.

In case `$_GET['z']` exists, I want to get the values

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => x [4] => y [5] => z )
```

And in case `$_GET['z']` doesn't exist, I want these values only

```
Array ( [0] => x [1] => y [2] => z )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you actually want. How is the array supposed to look like?

Comment: @Andreas add a better explanation, please check it.

Comment: What you want still isn't clear. If `$_GET['z']` is set, what should the final array look like?  If it is not set, what should the final array look like?

Comment: My new answer does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP 5.6, you can use the [splat operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) to unshift each element of `$a` instead of the array itself.

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$x = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

array_unshift($x, ...$a);
print_r($x);
```

which outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => x
    [4] => y
    [5] => z
)
```

I do not see any need for the temporary `$merging` array and subsequent `array_merge` at all — the following will do.

```
$array = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
if(isset($_GET['z'])){
   $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
   array_unshift($array, ...$a);
}
print_r($array);
```

Here array will be `['x', 'y', 'z']` if `$_GET['z']` is not set and `['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']` if it is set.

Before 5.6 you can simply use `array_splice` in the following form in place of `array_unshift`:

```
array_splice($x, 0, 0, $a);
```

Comment: well, the problem itself is that i need to assign all arrays to one single array since there is an `if-statement` that i have to add its array value inside too, And i don't think i can use `if-statement` inside a function.

Comment: I think you were hung up on using `array_merge`, but I edited the answer to show it is not necessary. Regardless, the way to unshift individual elements of one array onto another array is to use `array_unshift` with the splat operator or `array_splice`.

Comment: That solved it all, Pretty astonishing solution actually with less work in it. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be over-complicating things:

```
$result = isset($_GET['z']) ? array_merge(['a','b','c'],$x) : $x;
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Well, That way more efficient answer, But there is still the point of `array_unshift()` part, Since i need the arrays ordered.

Comment: @Axon I don't understand. My answer fits your requirement. Result will be `[a, b, c, x, y, z]` as you wanted because `$a` comes before `$x` in `array_merge`.  `array_unshift()` is a much more heavy operation because every time a new element is added (they're added one by one), the whole array has to be rekeyed.

Comment: In my question i define `$a array` if `isset($_GET['z'])`

Comment: @Axon It's an easy enough adjustment if the contents of `$a` shouldn't exist outside the `if` block. I've modified my answer. My bigger point is that I wouldn't use `array_unshift` to insert multiple elements if `array_merge` could do the job because the first is a lot more computationally expensive

Comment: For the record I agree with BeetleJuice that practically speaking, `array_merge` is the way to go here. But I wanted to reserve judgment on the approach and point out how to transform an array into a list of its constitutive elements — I think this was a more apparent concern in the original draft of the question.